# Can't extract data from beautiful_soup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm crawling a website(https://www.zhihu.com/people/xie-ke-41/followers), and i want to get all the followers' information. As you can see, some followers' information is bring with AJAX, I use the developers' tool in chrome and locate the url  [the url which has followers' information](http://%22https://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2%22)

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


zhihu_rl = 'https://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowersListV2'

data = {
'method': 'next',
'params': '{"offset":20,"order_by":"created","hash_id":"86858a7a4aa77d290364625efcaacb70"}'}

headers = {
'Host': 'www.zhihu.com',
'Origin': 'https://www.zhihu.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.zhihu.com/people/xie-ke-41/followers',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'X-Xsrftoken': 'foo',
'Cookie':'xxxxxxxxxxxx'}

rep = requests.post(url=zhihu_rl, data=data, headers=headers)

bsobj = BeautifulSoup(rep.text,  'html.parser')

print(bsobj.find_all('div', {'class': "zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard"}))
```

and an empty list returned.
i can see the information is developer's tool:
[image: thr information i see in developers' tool]
,why can't bs4 extract them?
PS:i can get all the div,but when i limit the attributes.it failed

Comment: I cannot access to the website. From what I have see, last line, there shouldn't be any spaces before item? `zm-profile-section-  item`

Comment: sorry,it's my spell mistake

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have escaped json, if you print the bsobj you can see output like:

```
{"r":0,
 "msg": ["<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"6327483c9e474097e7dbb2493a7f277c\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8\u4ed6<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"\u738b\u5728\u9014\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$wang-zai-tu-81\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic1.zhimg.com\/da8e974dc_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$wang-zai-tu-81\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\" class=\"zg-link author-link\" title=\"\u738b\u5728\u9014\"\n>\u738b\u5728\u9014<\/a><\/span><\/h2>\n\n<div class=\"summary-wrapper summary-wrapper--medium\">\n\n<span class=\"bio\"><\/span>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"details zg-gray\">\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\/followers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">1 \u5173\u6ce8\u8005<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\/asks\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u63d0\u95ee<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\/answers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">1 \u56de\u7b54<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/wang-zai-tu-81\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u8d5e\u540c<\/a>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/div>\n<\/div>","<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"a3596eaecae6f05f0ddf95dfcc6b5517\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"\u7075\u9b42\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$ling-hun-30-21\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic1.zhimg.com\/da8e974dc_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$ling-hun-30-21\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\" class=\"zg-link author-link\" title=\"\u7075\u9b42\"\n>\u7075\u9b42<\/a><\/span><\/h2>\n\n<div class=\"summary-wrapper summary-wrapper--medium\">\n\n<span class=\"bio\"><\/span>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"details zg-gray\">\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\/followers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u5173\u6ce8\u8005<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\/asks\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u63d0\u95ee<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\/answers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u56de\u7b54<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/ling-hun-30-21\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u8d5e\u540c<\/a>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/div>\n<\/div>","<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"74fad3af2b93f7da69c37eda64c31037\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"\u5f90\u6668\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$xu-chen-77-49\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic1.zhimg.com\/da8e974dc_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$xu-chen-77-49\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\" class=\"zg-link author-link\" title=\"\u5f90\u6668\"\n>\u5f90\u6668<\/a><\/span><\/h2>\n\n<div class=\"summary-wrapper summary-wrapper--medium\">\n\n<span class=\"bio\">\u4f1a\u8ba1\u5e08<\/span>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"details zg-gray\">\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\/followers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u5173\u6ce8\u8005<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\/asks\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u63d0\u95ee<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\/answers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u56de\u7b54<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/xu-chen-77-49\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u8d5e\u540c<\/a>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/div>\n<\/div>","<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"032b36abfbe05a30913c794a4b099629\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8\u5979<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"Shuai Zhang\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$shuai-zhang-49\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic2.zhimg.com\/v2-8aa42ff00873460e29444d62ff51acfd_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$shuai-zhang-49\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\" class=\"zg-link author-link\" title=\"Shuai Zhang\"\n>Shuai Zhang<\/a><\/span><\/h2>\n\n<div class=\"summary-wrapper summary-wrapper--medium\">\n\n<span class=\"bio\"><\/span>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"details zg-gray\">\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\/followers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">79 \u5173\u6ce8\u8005<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\/asks\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">1 \u63d0\u95ee<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\/answers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">119 \u56de\u7b54<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/shuai-zhang-49\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">174 \u8d5e\u540c<\/a>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/div>\n<\/div>","<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"6388162f5357ca1bd872dc0b6efe4802\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8\u4ed6<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"\u5468\u5468\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$zhou-zhou-69-22\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic1.zhimg.com\/da8e974dc_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$zhou-zhou-69-22\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\" class=\"zg-link author-link\" title=\"\u5468\u5468\"\n>\u5468\u5468<\/a><\/span><\/h2>\n\n<div class=\"summary-wrapper summary-wrapper--medium\">\n\n<span class=\"bio\"><\/span>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"details zg-gray\">\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\/followers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">4 \u5173\u6ce8\u8005<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\/asks\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">0 \u63d0\u95ee<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\/answers\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">7 \u56de\u7b54<\/a>\n\/\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/people\/zhou-zhou-69-22\" class=\"zg-link-gray-normal\">1 \u8d5e\u540c<\/a>\n<\/div>\n\n<\/div>\n<\/div>","<div class=\"zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard\">\n<div class=\"zg-right\">\n<button data-follow=\"m:button\" data-id=\"3a1a9da0e0bb4abe2554fa2a6032f27f\" class=\"zg-btn zg-btn-follow zm-rich-follow-btn small nth-0\">\u5173\u6ce8\u5979<\/button>\n<\/div>\n<a title=\"\u7f8e\u7f8e\u836f\u5242\u5e08\"\ndata-hovercard=\"p$t$sui-nuo-81\"\nclass=\"zm-item-link-avatar\"\nhref=\"\/people\/sui-nuo-81\">\n<img src=\"https:\/\/pic2.zhimg.com\/ae23b8e89725a24de650dee53e9a60a5_m.jpg\" class=\"zm-item-img-avatar\">\n<\/a>\n<div class=\"zm-list-content-medium\">\n<h2 class=\"zm-list-content-title\"><span class=\"author-link-line\">\n<a data-hovercard=\"p$t$sui-nuo-81\" href=\"https:\/\/www.zhihu.com\/people\/sui-nuo-81\" class=\"zg-link
```

Unfortunately it is also invalid *json* so we cannot call `req.json()` and get nice un-escaped html so you will have to do it manually using *string_escape*:

```
In [14]: rep = requests.post(url=zhihu_rl, data=data, headers=headers)

In [15]: bsobj = BeautifulSoup(rep.text.decode("string_escape"),  'lxml')

In [16]: ancs = (bsobj.find_all('div', {'class': 'zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard'}))

In [17]: len(ancs)
Out[17]: 20
```

It is also  *`zm-profile-section-item`* not  *`zm-profile-section-   item`*

Also in future never post login cookies, I could have full access to your account in a couple of minutes.

Comment: No worries, I would strongly suggest you change your password before someone else does http://s13.postimg.org/5vcsmev07/comp.png

Answer (score -2):

You have used good header combination otherwise the server may not recognize your header and it thinks that you don't have javascript enabled. In limiting the attribute use . for class and # for id. Other CSS selectors will also work fine. You need also to use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) for the javascript execution(ajax calls) since beautifulsoup lack this feature
Finally, make sure the website doesn't have anti-scraping protection. In that case, you need to use javascript runtimes like [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py)

Comment: i think  i already get the data,you can print bsobj to see it ,the problem is why can't beautifulsoap extract the items with attrs.

Comment: use regex to extract the data if you already have it. Other function to select is as follow 'print(bsobj.find_elements_by_class_name("zm-profile-card zm-profile-section-  item zg-clear no-hovercard"))'